# to dataframe from a CSV file with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe from a CSV that has multiple delimiters. The delimiter for the header(column names) of the CSV is a comma, the rest of the rows are TAB-delimited.

I've tried doing things like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv', names=['Code', 'Name'], header=None, skiprows=1, sep='\t')
```

It's not a big deal for me to skip the header row since I know what the column names will be any way, but the above isn't working for me. Is there a way I can parse the header row differently than the rest of the data, or is it possible for me to skip the header row and just delimit by TAB?

Comment: You can `open()` file, initialize regular `csv.reader()` and call `next()` on reader to obtain first line, then pass file handle instead of file name and pass column names in `names` argument. Like [this](https://tio.run/##HYlBCgMhEATvvmJuKsjCkksI@IW8IBAkjijJ6jBKNnm9O2xfurqL/iO3erkSz1k2ajzg1b9K7WVkaITVaNmpfHCR1hZCh3RTIIkJPFBcGEN8ijTJQQ0bdl/xN4w8p0I2yVoH@WR/bxUd9Hchbnv3qzCS14@h7ZwH). Or just split first line. [Code](https://tio.run/##DYrBCkIhEEX3fcXsRkGEaBOBv9AXBCE5ovQaB0feq6837@YcOFd@ozS@XKXPedRRoAmxwZfuuW7kF9FCVMi3E6ylDAEk@U4xPVc02QHHD2lg@g6TrVfZ6jDo0Doo60U93BuTA31X6e3QcF5OEvAx0M75Bw).

Comment: @OlvinRoght Okay, what if- instead of my CSV file being found in the same directory and a string I can pass, I'm trying to pass it an InputStream instead. I cannot do ```with open(myblob) as f:``` I end up getting this error ```TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InputStream```

Comment: Didn't understood. If you have string why to use `.read_csv()`? Anyway, you can initialize `io.StringIO` and pass it both to `.read_csv()` and `csv.reader()` *(to get fieldnames)*.

Comment: Why don't first work on the csv and replace commas in headers by tab-characters ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght so apparently pd.read_csv() works when passing InputStream. Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried ```with io.StringIO(myblob) as f:``` and ```with io.BytesIO(myblob) as f:``` to try and make this work, but no luck.

Comment: @LaurentB. I'm getting passed this csv, I could request this get changed, but I'd rather take care of it myself if I can.

Comment: @BlakeB9, you don't need `with`. Just initialize `stream = StringIO(myblob)` and then pass it to pandas `df = pd.read_csv(stream, names=next(csv.reader(stream)), sep='\t')`

Comment: @OlvinRoght thank you, but when trying ```stream = io.StringIO(myblob)``` I get this error ```TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not InputStream```

Comment: @BlakeB9, I have no idea what `InputStream` is, it's not a built-in type so I don't know exactly how to work with it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght ah okay, well here's what I can share if it helps at all. It's a file like object representing an input blob. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.inputstream?view=azure-python

Comment: @BlakeB9, well, simplest will be to use `stream = io.StringIO(myblob.read().decode())`. If CSV files you're working with are relatively small it should be okay to keep it like this. Anyway `DataFrame` will consume much more memory than raw string data which will be vanished by garbage collector once `.read_csv()` finish processing.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thank you so much! Yes the CSV should be pretty small. I used what you suggested and also changed ```myblob``` from the ```pd.read_csv()``` to ```df = pd.read_csv(stream, names=next(csv.reader(stream)), header=None, skiprows=1, sep='\t')``` and it seems to work perfectly. Thank you again!

Comment: @BlakeB9, I think you can *(should)* omit both `header` and `skiprows` arguments if adding them was a part of your previous attempts.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
with open('csvfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    header = f.readline()
    content = f.readlines()

df = pd.DataFrame([ {i:j for i,j in zip(header.strip().split(","), 
     r.strip().split("\t"))}  for r in content ])
```

Comment: `header, *content = f`

Comment: In general I see no reason to reimplement `csv.DictReader`. If you want to parse csv before initialize `DataFrame`, that's the way to go.

Comment: I do not figure how to deal with different delimiters in header and all other lines with DictReader.

Comment: Just don't. Read first line either with regular `csv,reader()` or just split it manually and pass header names to `DictReader` constructor.

Comment: Like [this](https://tio.run/##LYw7CsMwDIZ3n0KbbQhZupRCttADdO5iYpkYYlsooo/Tu3YaIZD4/gd9ZS35ciWuNSYqLLDsL3W@5LJ3O7Qlr9Q7ygqFMBvdPCFuOLarbdfDTUEbRueRYeol4xwXeRzAhAEyfsR0zCeydgCPW0xRkCf9FG2PDh9anvw4O3F3dgnNP2Fr/QE). It should also be a bit more memory efficient.

Comment: @RicVillalba Okay, what if- instead of my CSV file being found in the same directory and a string I can pass, I'm trying to pass it an InputStream instead. I cannot do ```with open(myblob) as f:``` I end up getting this error ```TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InputStream``` sorry- working in the cloud.